# Derivative of cross entropy loss in word2ve

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, word2vec

I am referring to this question: [Derivative of cross entropy loss in word2vec](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173593/derivative-of-cross-entropy-loss-in-word2vec)

$CE(w, \hat{w}) = -\sum_{k}^{|V|} w_klog(\frac{\exp(w_k^T \hat{r})}{\sum_{j}^{|V|}exp(w_j^T\hat{r})})$

$= -\sum_{k}^{|V|} w_klog(\exp(w_k^T \hat{r}) +    w_klog(\sum_{j}^{|V|}exp(w_j^T\hat{r}))$

How is the $ \sum_{k}^{|V|} $ disappearing in the second term? I think it has something to do with the one hot vector, but I cant figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Only the term under the log has been split. The $ \Sigma_k^{|V|}w_k $ term is still there, being common among the $\log(a/b) = \log(a) - \log(b)$ terms.

Later on, the first term is $\Sigma_k^{|V|}w_k \log \exp(w_k^T \hat r)$ only has $w_k$ dependent on k, so at the ith label remains, and then the partial derivative w.r.t. r will be $w_i$.

The second term will have two sum terms, each with their own index and that will yield a probability term w.r.t. the summation and the corresponding $w_x$ term.